# How to get return value of WebMethod from JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am tryring to get the return value of WebMethod from JQuery call, but I am getting "undefined" message. Here is my code below

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Receipt/BarcodeEntered",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg.d); // This displays "Undefined"
                    alert(msg);   // This displays the whole html
                 }
});
```

and the WebMethod is below

```
[WebMethod]
public static string BarcodeEntered() 
{
    return "test_string";
}
```

how can I get the value from WebMethod and display it on client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebMethod officialy only can return XML or JSON.
Default is json, so whatever you return gets converted to json

**change in JQuery** `dataType: "json",`

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Receipt/BarcodeEntered",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                 }
});
```

and you should return class not single string. because string can not be converted valid json object.

```
public class SampleClass{
    public string Message {set; get;}
}

[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public SampleClass BarcodeEntered()
{

        return new SampleClass(){
        Message  = "Sample message"
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return JSON, let me write down an example.

```
public JsonResult DoStuff()
{
    string text = "text";

    return Json(text, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working demo I am using this in my asp.net page. The data is will be in d property.

JQuery code.

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Subfolder/MyPageName.aspx/myWebMethodName",
    data: '{}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
      if (msg.d == "OK") {
       alert("OK")
      } else {
         alert(msg.d);
      }
    }
   });
```

C# Code

```
[WebMethod]
public static string myWebMethodName()
{ 
   return "OK";
}
```